# Time Complexity of Python `rfind()`

Tags: python, indexing, time-complexity, big-o

I'm wondering if using `index` or `rindex` would increase the time complexity to O(n^2) in a loop such as:

```py
for c in s:
    if s.index(c) == s.rindex(c):
        return c
```

I'm not proficient in C. However, I researched the source code for `rindex.` Which can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/29f1b0bb1ff73dcc28f0ca7e11794141b6de58c9/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12235). I did notice that they are using some sort of nested while loop, which technically would make the time complexity O(n^2), but that is not always the case.

Edit: Also, the code above seems to be more efficient than something like this:

```py
 h1 = dict()
    
 for index, element in enumerate(s):
     h1[element] = h1.get(element, 0) + 1
    
 for key, value in h1.items():
     if value == 1:
         return key
```

That said, please enlighten me in understanding if the code above is O(n) or O(n^2) and why it is more efficient.

Tested with a string of length 100k.

I believe the code is O(n^2) due to using an O(n) inside a for a loop. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes, the above code is O(N^2)

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you are preforming an O(n) operation with the for loop, and the `s.rindex(c)` is preforming also an O(n) operation. Therefore, them multiplied is O(n^2).